# MERN Redux stack deleting a user by their id issue. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, axios

On this day I am trying to send an axios.delete to a route on my backend to delete a user from the database.

However I am confused on how to access the user id. I am using React with redux. I am getting an undefined for the props.regauth.id

forgive me for i know not how noob i am

here is actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';


const REG_USER_LOGOUT = 'req_logout_user';

export const regLogoutUser = () => {
        return async function (props, dispatch) {
                let id = Number(props.regauth.id)
                await axios
                .delete(`/api/users:${id}`)
                .then(res => dispatch({type: REG_USER_LOGOUT, payload: res }))
        }
}
```

Down near the bottom of this file i am trying to access the props.regauth.id in a onClick to dispatch() with the proper id so my action creator can delete.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { DropdownItem, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle, Dropdown } from 'reactstrap';
import team3 from '../../assets/img/team/3.jpg';
import Avatar from '../common/Avatar';
import { regLogoutUser } from '../../actions/index';

const ProfileDropdown = (props) => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    
    <Dropdown
      nav
      inNavbar
      isOpen={dropdownOpen}
      toggle={toggle}
      onMouseOver={() => {
        let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        windowWidth > 992 && setDropdownOpen(true);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        windowWidth > 992 && setDropdownOpen(false);
      }}
    >
      <DropdownToggle nav className="pr-0">
        <Avatar src={team3} />
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu right className="dropdown-menu-card">
        <div className="bg-white rounded-soft py-2">
          <DropdownItem className="font-weight-bold text-warning" href="#!">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="crown" className="mr-1" />
            <span>Go Pro</span>
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem divider />
          <DropdownItem href="#!">Set status</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem tag={Link} to="/dashboard/pages/profile">
            Profile &amp; account
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem href="#!">Feedback</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem divider />
          <DropdownItem tag={Link} to="/dashboard/pages/settings">
            Settings
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem tag={Link} onClick={() => { dispatch(regLogoutUser(props.regauth.id)) }}to="/authentication/basic/logout">
            Logout
          </DropdownItem>
        </div>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    regauth: state.regauth,
    auth: state.auth
  }
}
```

Here is the object showing up on localhost:5000/api/users that i am trying to get access to the _id property but dont know how....

````
{"_id":"6068f03d9f46de05726402cc","email":"play@play.com","created":"2021-04-03T22:46:21.858Z"}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between how you are defining `regLogoutUser` and how you are calling it. Compare these two and see if you can spot the problems:

```
export const regLogoutUser = () => {
    return async function (props, dispatch) {
        let id = Number(props.regauth.id)
...
```

```
dispatch(regLogoutUser(props.regauth.id))
```

You are calling `regLogoutUser` with an id, but it doesn't take any arguments.

---

The proper way to define a [thunk action creator](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) is to accept arguments like the `id` as arguments of the outer function.  The inner function takes `dispatch` as a prop.

You are also combining `async`/`await` and `Promise`/`then` syntax which can be confusing.

Try this:

```
export const regLogoutUser = (id) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const res = await axios.delete(`/api/users:${id}`) // double check this path
        dispatch({type: REG_USER_LOGOUT, payload: res.data })
    }
}
```